Is this phrase construction correct grammatically?
Consider the phrase my friend(a native English speaker from UK) used in a text

That sounds awful yes it would understandable bother you.

Is this sentence construction correct? I think it is a typo.

It's incorrect. (It seems like it should be two sentences instead of one. "Understandable" seems to be a typo for "understandably.") A more grammatically correct way of saying the same thing would be this: "That sounds awful, yes. It would understandably bother you."

In texting, users don't usually pay much attention to grammar.

That sounds awful yes it would understandable bother you.

is ungrammatical.
There are two sentences here.
A workable version could also consist of a question and an answer.  (Another possibility is to have two statements, as in the comment: That sounds awful, yes.  It would understandably bother you.)
In the former, we could add the do-support Does:
That sounds awful? (or Does that sound awful?) Yes, it would understandably bother you.
